# Wait for object to finish moving, then do action

Tags: java, events, timer

I'm wondering if there is any built in way in Java to wait until something is finished, then keep going in the code.

In my case, I move an object from `x` to `destinationX` by `50px` per frame when I press the object. To wait for that movement to finish before I keep going in my code I use a `Timer` atm, but I'm worried that might not be the best solution if someone runs on low fps.

Is there any way to do this without using a bunch of flags or a Timer? I looked into `Events` but can't find decent instructions on how I could apply it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with states (= an integer) and change states once a condition is met, like

```
if(state == 1) moveObject();
if(state == 2) keepGoing();
```

and you change state from 1 to 2 once you reached the destination in `moveObject();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your actions in different threads and use Thread.join() as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html).